# 30th Artifact question

Tags: tap-titans

In the in-game tutorial, it says there are 30 artifacts. And after searching around I have come to know that there are only 29, one of them was removed from the game.

I couldn't find what that 30th artifact was or what it did and why was it so broken that the developers removed it.
Can someone shed some light on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a complete list of all 30 artifacts](http://tap-titans.wikia.com/wiki/Artifacts)

Brew of Absorption has been removed for now.